# AWS Amplify directing to non-existent directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I uploaded my app to Amplify the other day, and I have been having the issue of it trying to go to a directory that doesn't exist on load. I fixed it with a rewrites and redirects rule, but for some reason, it just broke. 
For context, the directory that does exist is- "somedomain.com/login_signup/login.html/". In no place have I specified that directory as the home directory, first of all.

Secondly, no matter what combination of rewrites and redirects I use, it continues to direct to this directory which doesn't exist. Directory shown below. 
"somedomain.com/login_signup/login.html/login_signup/login" which then results in an xml error page.

- Are there any redirects/rewrites for Amplify that redirects ONLY on first load?
- Where do I specify the entry point for my webpage? I never specified it.
- Why is Amplify directing itself to a directory that doesn't exist? How do I stop it from doing so?